# Why can't I use length function inside input function in SAS?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have a code that converts a character to numeric using the informat and I'm using length function as the value of informat.

However, I'm having error with this approach.

Background of this problem is that the informat before was fixed value. I want to enhance the code for the informat to be flexible and remove the fixed value.

Before code:

```
data work.test;
emp_input = '168643123'
emp_value = input(emp_input, 6.);
run;
```

My current testcode:

```
data work.test;
emp_input = '168643123'
emp_value = input(emp_input, length(emp_input).);
run;
```

I expect the result that character '168643123' would be converted to numeric 168643123.

Using before code the output for this would be: numeric 168643.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid syntax. You have to use inputn an and then generate an string for the format.

```
data work.test;
  emp_input = '168643123';
  emp_value = inputn(emp_input, cats(put(length(emp_input),3.),'.'));
run;
```

But better use Use BEST32. for all generic numbers of up 32 chars length.

```
data work.test;
  emp_input = '168643123';
  emp_value = input(emp_input, BEST32.);
run;
```

Comment: There isn't really an INFORMAT named `BEST` f you use it SAS will silently just convert it to the normal numeric informat. There is a format name `BEST` that adjusts the display format used to best fit a numeric value into a limited number of characters.  But the reverse concept of what number to best translate a specific character string into doesn't make sense.  You just want it to translate the character string into THE number that the string represents.

Comment: I will try this sir and get back for the results

Answer (score 1):

INPUT requires a text value for the second parameter.

INPUTN() or INPUTC() can take the second parameter as a string/character/variable and use that to apply the format. You do have to convert it to a string first.

Answer (score 1):

Why?  The INPUT function is happy to adjust when the width of the informat is larger than the length of the string you are reading.  Just use the maximum width that the informat allows.

```
emp_value = input(emp_input,32.);
```

If you did want to limit the number of characters read (perhaps there are letters after the digits?) then you can use the INPUTN() function (or INPUTC() function for character results).  Let's test by appending some X's to the end of the string and using an informat whose width stops before the X's.

```
emp_value = inputn(cats(emp_input,'XXX'),cats(length(emp_input),'.'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. This is based on all your answers. Thank you very much!

```
data work.test;
emp_input = '168643123'
emp_value = inputn(emp_input, cats(length(emp_input),'.'));
run;
```